# Error writing to nodejs socket (TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object)

Tags: node.js, sockets

Using electron I am trying to write out some bytes on a TCP socket. I am using Buffer.from to convert to buffer before calling write, but am still getting the above error. I have simplified it down to just creating an empty ArrayBuffer and calling Buffer.from

```
var abuff = new ArrayBuffer(8 + encodedBuffer.length);
console.log(Buffer.from(abuff));
socket.write(Buffer.from(abuff));
```

TypeError: Invalid data, chunk must be a string or buffer, not object
The console.log shows the following:

```
Uint8Array(51) [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

and not Buffer?

Versions in electron:
ares:"1.10.1-DEV"
atom-shell:"1.7.9"
chrome:"58.0.3029.110"
electron:"1.7.9"
http_parser:"2.7.0"
modules:"54"
node:"7.9.0"
openssl:"1.0.2k"
uv:"1.11.0"
v8:"5.8.283.38"
zlib:"1.2.11"

For anyone seeing this type of problem - This code was in the "renderer" process of Electron, the problem was the Buffer object in the "renderer" did not create a Buffer object from Buffer.from.

To solve I used IPC to send request from the renderer to the main process and let the main process manage the socket communication.

Answer (score 1):

As is said in error, chunk can be only type [string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) or [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html).
So we have few solutions for your problem.
First one, just convert your object to string with `JSON.stringify(<your data to send>)`, and than you can decode it on the other side.
Or you can use `object mode`, more [here](http://nodesource.com/blog/understanding-object-streams/). 

I've tried to test your code and it works.

```
var net = require('net');
var encodedBuffer = 9;
var abuff = new ArrayBuffer(8 + encodedBuffer.length);

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
  socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
  console.log(Buffer.from(abuff));
  socket.write(Buffer.from(abuff));
  socket.pipe(socket);
});

server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

And when I start app and make request to server from another command line session `nc 127.0.0.1 1337`, I see output in server window.

Comment: Why doesn't Buffer.from create a buffer? Maybe that is the more pertinent question?

Comment: @StephenJames I don't know what do you pass to `Buffer.from()`, but in documentation https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_from_array said that you can pass array or buffer to Buffer.from(buffer). If you can provide data, which you want to create buffer from, it would be easier to answer

Comment: The data is binary data and shouldn't be relevant to the three lines of code. why would an ArrayBuffer passed to Buffer.from not create a buffer that could be handled by socket.write

Comment: @StephenJames, are you using net module for sockets? https://nodejs.org/api/net.html

Comment: What I am thinking is that I am on the renderer process and it has a different Buffer object than the main process. I plan on testing this out tomorrow.

Comment: And yes I am using the net module

Comment: @StephenJames added my example of code. Please check.

Comment: When I moved the code from the electron renderer to the main process it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that I was trying to use the socket code in the renderer process of the electron app and the buffer implementation there is different than for the main process.
When I moved the socket send to the main process it worked just as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in node version 8.9.4,
I changed node version to 11.11.0. and the problem is disappeared.